# e.preventDefault prevent click

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to just test how the e.preventDefault() works.
I would think it would stop the click event from happening.

```
     $(document).ready(function( )
     {

       $("button").click(function(e)
       {

         e.preventDefault();  

          alert('button clicked');

       });

      });
```

I have a button. What is the purpose of e.preventDefault().
From what I read, it will prevent the action which in this case is the click.

Note that in the above example, the alert message still show. How does e.preventDefault() work for a button click. I know if it was a hyperlink, it would prevent the hyperlink from going to it target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

preventDefault is to prevent default, browser action. So if you will put something like:

```
$("a").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();})
```

click on links will do nothing. Or on submit button - form won't be submitted

Comment: However, it should be noted that to prevent a form from being submitted, it is better to prevent the default action for the form object's `submit` event than the default action of the submit button for the `click` event. Keep in mind that forms can (and should be able to) be used with the keyboard.

Comment: @PointedEars Can you please explain a case when this will not work? Just want to clear out this question for myself. Never thought about this before. I see that this can be a problem when there are more than one buttons and if event is not on the one which is "clicked" with Enter, but if there is only one button - click event on submit btn. is called even if I press enter in input field or with space when btn. is in focus.

Comment: You talk as if you had tested this in just a few graphical Web browsers and are now applying that knowledge to all UAs. That is thin ice. I cannot provide you with results from a test series (yet) if that's what you are after. Suffice it for me to say that good application design has single points of failure. You want to prevent form submission *regardless* how your form is structured: whether it has no submit button, one or two, whether the default submit button is the first or the second one, which one has focus; whether it's submitted through button click, keyboard shortcut, or other means.

Answer (score 0):

What it prevents is that DOM object receiving the "click".  So, if you're button was to submit a form, it won't submit it now.  The `alert()` afterwards will be executed regardless since you're saying, hey! stop the click, and then do this!

**More Reading**

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault

Comment: Wrong.  The DOM object does receive the `click` event, that is why its `click` event listener is triggered (by the handler) in the first place.  `preventDefault()` prevents the default action for the event on the object.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot stop the click from happening because what you have set up there is an event handler that executes *after* the event has triggered.

Answer (score 0):

`$.preventDefault();` will prevent the 'Default' action from happening.  For instance if you take an anchor link that already has an `href` assigned to it and then add the `preventDefault();` to said anchor it will no longer link.

Comment: Wrong.  There is no "'Default' event".  There is usually a default *action* for each event on an object, in this case the navigate action for the `click` event of the `a` element (specified by its `href` attribute), that is prevented by `preventDefault()`.

Comment: The issue is the word 'event' that I'm using as opposed to 'action'?  Looking to correct.

Comment: From what I can tell terminology was incorrect but the context was correct.  [openjs](http://www.openjs.com/articles/prevent_default_action/)  [javascript.about] (http://javascript.about.com/library/bldisdef.htm/)  I'll correct the term.  Seems like a weird thing to get down voted for instead of just getting a comment back to change the term.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer needs a complete rewrite before I can responsibly release my downvote.

Comment: Why is that? Are you saying that what I have written is still incorrect?  How so?  I'm trying to learn here just like everyone else, if you don't want to up vote that's fine but a specific reasoning would be welcome.  I don't see anything different in your explanation other than the word "usually" in relation to their being a default action.  If there's no default action than nothing will be prevented.  The answer is still valid.

Comment: Believe of me what you want; I know what I am talking about. Your answer does need serious rewrite before it is acceptable: There is no `$.preventDefault()`; it's a method of the *event* object instead. The quotes around "'Default'" need to be removed and "default" lowercased. It's wrong to say "the anchor will not link"; instead, when the link is activated *and* scripting is enabled, navigation will not take place. Given other, better answers, it might be better to just delete this one. A wrong or misleading answer does more harm (to the community) than one not given.

Comment: So besides the `$.preventDefault()` issue you have everything else is grammar based?  So in your opinion do you need to make a step by step analysis of all the possible circumstances?  Sure scripting may be off and the answer wouldn't work then.  Sure if the user doesn't click on the link itself it won't do anything.  But to list that on every answer; you might as well ask me to tell the user how to type.  Odd that the answer you voted up didn't have that sort of scrutiny attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that without adding your own Click callback function there is still an Event that will fire in the browser - e.g. for an "a" tag this would be to load the URL in the href attribute, for a submit button it would be to Post/Get to the URL in the Form "Action" attribute - in both cases e.preventDefault() would stop this happening

Comment: [`a` _element_, not "'a' tag"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1).  A tag of itself does nothing, it is not even represented in the document tree.  Elements are represented in the document tree by element objects.

Comment: @PointedEars - Thanks for pointing that out. However I think, within the context of my answer the meaning of a "tag" is likely to be sufficient enough to indicate the intent of the statement without giving rise to ambiguity. I frequently contact our web-dev guys at Yahoo! with requests like "Can you please add the xyz class to the a 'tags'" and they don't seem to have any issues understanding what I'm asking for. But again thanks for taking the "time" to point this out.

Comment: Since you had to resort to sarcasm: Incompetence comes in small packages.