# jQuery DataTables and Columnfilterwidget Reset all filters button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, reset

I am new to Javascript.So my question is a little silly.

I was looking for Reset all filter button for Columnfilterwidget and found this code.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnResetAllFilters = function (oSettings, bDraw/default true/) {
for(iCol = 0; iCol < oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length; iCol++) {
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = '';
}
$('.filter-term').remove();
oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = '';
if(typeof bDraw === 'undefined') bDraw = true;
if(bDraw) this.fnDraw();
}
```

I need to bind it to a button to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
 $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnResetAllFilters = function (oSettings, bDraw/default true/) {
    for(iCol = 0; iCol < oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length; iCol++) {
    oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = '';
    }
    $('.filter-term').remove();
    oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = '';
    if(typeof bDraw === 'undefined') bDraw = true;
    if(bDraw) this.fnDraw();
    }

});
});
```

But it doesn't work, all i get on button click is my page get's refreshed.
What i am doing wrong here???

UPDATED

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();})
$("button").click(function(){
console.log("afterbutton");
 $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnResetAllFilters = function (oSettings, bDraw) {
console.log("insidefunction");
    for(iCol = 0; iCol < oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length; iCol++) {
    oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = '';
    }
    $('.filter-term').remove();
    oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = '';
    if(typeof bDraw === 'undefined') bDraw = true;
    if(bDraw) this.fnDraw();
    }

});
});
```

Now page is not refreshing, also code is not woking,
The console only shows till afterbutton message i click on button.

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Thank you so much for the reply, as per your suggestion i've updated my code(I took button click event outside the `$(document).ready(function()`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnResetAllFilters = function (oSettings, bDraw) {
        for(iCol = 0; iCol < oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length; iCol++) {
        oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = '';
        }
        $('.filter-term').remove();
        oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = '';
        if(typeof bDraw === 'undefined') bDraw = true;
        if(bDraw) this.fnDraw();
        }

    } );

    // button click event
    $("button").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // 'myDataTable' is the name you gave the datatable at initialisation - oTable or similar
            table.fnResetAllFilters();
      });
```

This still refreshes my page on button click, But if i take button click event inside `$(document).ready(function()` then i get error as `table.fnResetAllFilters();` is not a function.  `table = $('#example').DataTable({` this is how i initialize the Datatable.

Comment: Maybe your default button click functionality is causing the page to refresh. If so, you need to to use preventDefault().  [stackoverflow.com/questions/12064164/e-preventdefault-prevent-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064164/e-preventdefault-prevent-click)

Comment: `$('.filter-term').remove();` using this i am able to remove the filters but table and filters are not reset after it with `fnDraw();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the preventDefault() to your original button click listener, you've actually added another one.

Modify your code so it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("afterbutton");
      ...
```

It also looks like you've included the function definition inside your button click code.

It needs to look something more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// function definition
 $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnResetAllFilters = function (oSettings, bDraw/default true/) {
    for(iCol = 0; iCol < oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length; iCol++) {
    oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = '';
    }
    $('.filter-term').remove();
    oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = '';
    if(typeof bDraw === 'undefined') bDraw = true;
    if(bDraw) this.fnDraw();
    }
});

// button click event
$("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // 'myDataTable' is the name you gave the datatable at initialisation - oTable or similar
        myDataTable.fnResetAllFilters();
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed the code as per your suggestion but still my function is not getting executed. `$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnResetAllFilters = function (oSettings, bDraw) {
console.log("insidefunction");
    for(iCol = 0; iCol < oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length; iCol++) {
    oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = '';
    }
    $('.filter-term').remove();
    oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = '';
    if(typeof bDraw === 'undefined') bDraw = true;
    if(bDraw) this.fnDraw();
    }
`

Comment: Can you see your messages in the console?

Comment: No error. onclick console gives afterbutton message, but the function after it doesnt get executed, and when i put `$('.filter-term').remove(); this.fnDraw();` after `console.log("afterbutton");` my filters get cleared after button click but table and filter values remain same, they don't get updated. Also i get error this.fnDraw is not a function.

Comment: Problem solved have to add it `$('#dataTable').dataTable().fnResetAllFilters();` like this , Thank you so much for efforts you put in to help me.

Comment: I am facing an issue, after reset button click my table is getting redrawn but my filters are not getting updated, the filtered terms are not coming in the filters drop down.

Comment: You mean the selectlists are being reset to their original state? Is your whole page being refreshed?

Comment: selectlists are not getting reset. the options i selected after reset they disappear from from the selectlist.

Comment: I don't really understand. The options are disappearing from the selectlists?  This sounds like an issue with the way you populate your selectlists.  Also, this should be in a separate question.

Comment: Added question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080959/jquery-datatables-and-columnfilterwidget-reset-filter-issue)

Comment: Hey guys, yeah this is a lot more than just button click problem. If understand the situation correctly the problem is in the ColumnFilterWidgets plugin I've referred in a different question. Yes as far I can see the plugin doesn't open up any API for you or any methods to -reset- it to defaults. I'm afraid you'll have to add this to the plugin. So how about to start with the sample case at http://jsfiddle.net/ (use External resources, to bring dataTables and plugin sources)